# Html2canvas Ignores object-fit for image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I've been trying to make use of html2canvas to take a screenshot of a  element

I noticed an image inside the div element that uses the object-fit property becomes stretched after the html2canvas screenshot

Is there a walk around for this. Here is my code

```
<script>window.addEventListener('load', function () {

      
 var bigCanvas = $("<div>").appendTo('body');
 var scaledElement = $("#Element").clone()
 .css({
  'transform': 'scale(1,1)',
  'transform-origin': '0 0'
 })
 .appendTo(bigCanvas);
 
 var oldWidth = scaledElement.width();
 var oldHeight = scaledElement.height();

 var newWidth = oldWidth * 1;
 var newHeight = oldHeight * 1;
 
 bigCanvas.css({
   'width': newWidth,
   'height': newHeight
 })


 html2canvas(bigCanvas, {
   onrendered: function(canvasq) {
   var image = document.getElementById('image');
  image.style.width='300px';
 
   image.src = canvasq.toDataURL();
   
    bigCanvas.remove() ;
   }
 });}) </script>
```

While html goes as

```
<div id="Element" class="container">
  
<div class="bg-light p-3 text-center">

<h3>iPhone 12 Pro Max</h3>

<div class="m-2 shadow" style="height:400px;width:100%;">

<img src="img/agency.jpeg" style="object-fit:cover;height:100%;width:100%;" />
</div>

<h4>Now available for free</h4>

</div>

</div>

<div class="container" style="width:100%;border:2px solid black;overflow:hidden">

 <img src="" id="image" style="max-width:100%;"/>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, unfortunally it seems that html2cavas doesn't support the object-fit property but i resolve with flexbox and the result it's good, it's important to set the width and height for parent node:

```
 .logo-preview-inner {
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: solid 1px #e6e6e6;
      margin: 0 auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      position: relative;
      img {
        width: 100%;
      }
```

where the class .logo-preview-inner is the parent node and the image is the child
i hope to help you!

Comment: The code you posted is not CSS, and also wouldn't really _solve_ the issue, just cram the image into the already defined size. But yes, you are right, it's not supported.